# Why am I getting UnicodeDecodeError here?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a python script to find duplicate files in a usb flash drive.

The proccess I am following is creating a list of the file names, hashing each file, then creating an inverse dictionary. However somewhere in the proccess I am getting a `UnicodeDecodeError`. Could someone help me understand what's going on?

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from collections import defaultdict
import hashlib

my_path = r"F:/"

files_in_dir = [ file for file in listdir(my_path) if isfile(join(my_path, file)) ]
file_hashes = dict()

for file in files_in_dir:
    file_hashes[file] = hashlib.md5(open(join(my_path, file), 'r').read()).digest()

inverse_dict = defaultdict(list)

for file, file_hash in file_hashes.iteritems():
    inverse_dict[file_hash].append(file)

inverse_dict.items()
```

The error that I face is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Fotis\Desktop\check_dup.py", line 12, in <module>
    file_hashes[file] = hashlib.md5(open(join(my_path, file), 'r').read()).digest()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\encodings\cp1253.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 2227: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: @Martijn Pieters It's python 3. I will retag the question appropriatelly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to read a file that is not encoded in the default platform encoding (`cp1253`). By opening the file in text mode (`r`) Python 3 will try and decode the file contents to unicode. You didn't specify an encoding, so the platform preferred encoding is used.

Open the files in binary mode instead, using `rb` as the mode. Since you are only calculating the MD5 hash (a function that expects bytes), you should not be using text mode anyway.